# Transfer ERC20 tokens using another contract. tx.origin vs msg.sender

Tags: contract-development, transactions, erc-20

I have a basic ERC20 token(TMP coin) contract like mentioned in [ERC20 Token example](https://ethereum.org/token).

In ERC20 token example code transfer function transferring tokens from `msg.sender` to another account, but why we are not using `tx.origin`?

How can I transfer TMP coin tokens from one account to another by using another smart contract(contract XYZ)?

Answer (score 1):

**`tx.origin` vs `msg.sender`:**

`msg.sender` - the address of the direct caller (can be contract or externally owned account)

`tx.origin` - the address of the caller the transaction originates from (always an externally owned account).

It is best practice to not use `tx.origin` unless you really need to know the origin.

You should **not** use `tx.origin` for verification as that would expose you to potential attacks ([tx.origin attack](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/security-considerations.html#tx-origin)). The example in the Solidity docs is outdated and can't be reproduced with `.transfer()` anymore but there are ways around it.

**Transfer ERC20 from A to B:**

In order to transfer tokens from account **A** to account **B** using Contract **C** you would need to do the following:

1. From **A** call the ERC20 function `approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)` 
   and pass the address of **C** as spender, plus the amount he is allowed to 
   send. This would tell the Token Contract that your contract **C** is allowed to transfer the specified amount from your address **A**.
2. From **C** call the ERC20 function `transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)`. Passing in `from: A.address` and `to: B.address`

Answer (score 0):

`msg.sender` can be a Contract address as well, while `tx.origin` is always an EOA. http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/account-types-gas-and-transactions.html#eoa-vs-contract-accounts

Using `msg.sender` allows contracts to receive funds from other contract accounts as opposed to just EOAs.